# Как получить доступ к драйверу видеокарты?

Tags: драйвер, delphi

Как получить доступ к драйверу видеокарты и как можно узнать список функций драйвера?

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/50386/как-получить-прямой-доступ-к-видеоадаптеру

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно прямой доступ к драйверу видеокарты закрыт, поскольку сама Windows управляет тем, что отображается на экране. Крайне редко этот доступ вообще требуется, достаточно использовать вызовы DirectX. Если хочется узнать, что и как можно делать с драйвером, то нужно зайти на сайт производителя графики (например, AMD или Intel), найти соответствующий SDK и примеры работы с ним.